# How to keep certain number but remove the remaining text in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to keep numbers in the red box and split or delete what's behind. And I have thousands of data like that with different lengths. Can someone show me how to split that in excel?

[image: text]

Here are some of the data.

```html
004193025.jpg
004193037臭鼬奇蹟一發-動物造型屁.jpg
004193042動物的吶喊.jpg
004193052   新銅管樂器小物包.jpg
004203015 日本神像大全.jpg
004203016誰得俺得系列-人形_拖車.jpg
004204001誰得俺得系列-骷顱機體P2.jpg
004204002香菇夾.jpg
004212001日本風格和食器P2.jpg
004212018寵物們的窩.jpg
004212021富士冰.jpg
004212023貓與櫃子P2.jpg
004212024趣味小雞賽跑競賽.jpg
004212030桌上迷你遊戲盤-3D AceP2.jpg
004212034 可動式眼鏡-ALL STYLE篇.jpg
004212036新銅管樂器吊飾P15.jpg
004213007可動生物系列-動感蠍子P2.jpg
004213008 藥袋造型口罩套.jpg
004213009收音機造型提袋_錄音帶小物包.jpg
004213011日本塑膠袋造型環保袋.jpg
```

Comment: There are q&a on here showing how to do that.

Comment: Which version of Excel?

Comment: Something like `=LEFT(A1,MATCH(1,--ISERROR(MID(A1,SEQUENCE(LEN(A1)),1)*1),0)-1)`

Comment: @JvdV, nice. I forgot about sequence, and changed my answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the easiest way without a formula.

1. copy the first section of the number to B1
2. Select B2, then press Ctrl + E

Comment: I tested your solution against your data set and it did not provide consistent successful results. I updated my formula and it works flawlessly. You can obviously use what you please, but I did provide you with a viable solution...

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN("p",,IF(ISNUMBER(MID(L4,SEQUENCE(len(A2)),1)+0),MID(L4,SEQUENCE(len(a2)),1),"p")),"p","")
```